# ScrollWindowEx() scrolls the window contents incorrectly

Tags: c++, winapi, scroll

For example, I created a **simple window**:

```
WNDCLASSEX wcex;

const wchar_t className[] = L"TESTWINDOW";
WNDCLASSEX checkRegWC;

    if(GetClassInfoExW(hInstance, className, &checkRegWC) == 0)
    {
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style = CS_DBLCLKS | CS_PARENTDC | CS_GLOBALCLASS;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)TestWindowWndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = NULL;
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName = className;
    wcex.hIconSm = NULL;
    RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
    }

testWndWidth = nWidth;
hTestWindowWnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL, className, L"", WS_CHILDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, x, y, 150, 100, hwndParent, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if(!hTestWindowWnd)
    return;

ShowWindow(hTestWindowWnd, SW_SHOW);
UpdateWindow(hTestWindowWnd);
```

And here it's **window proc**:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK TestWindowWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(uMsg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
        {
        break;
        }
        case WM_ERASEBKGND:
        {
        RECT rc;
        GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);
        HBRUSH br = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255,255,255));
        FillRect((HDC)wParam, &rc, br);
        DeleteObject(br);
        return TRUE;
        }
        case WM_PAINT:
        {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hDC = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        HFONT oldFont = (HFONT)SelectObject(hDC, hEditFont);

        int textPosY = 0;
        int lineNum = 0;

            //fill the window with text
            for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            {
            strcpy(textData, "String___#");
            itoa(lineNum, buf, 10);
            strcat(textData, buf);

            TextOutA(hDC, 10, textPosY, textData, strlen(textData));
            lineNum++;
            textPosY += 13;
            }

        SelectObject(hDC, oldFont);
        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        return 0;
        }
    }

return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

And now I want to scroll 13 units down of my window content using `ScrollWindowEx()` function :

```
RECT updateRect;
DWORD dwTime = 1000;

ScrollWindowEx(hTestWindowWnd, 0, 13, NULL, NULL, NULL, &updateRect, MAKELONG(SW_SMOOTHSCROLL | SW_SCROLLCHILDREN, dwTime));

InvalidateRect(hTestWindowWnd, &updateRect, true);
UpdateWindow(hTestWindowWnd);
```

After calling `ScrollWindowEx()` the `updateRect` contains:
left = 0, top = 0, right = 150, bottom = **1**

[image]

But it should be like this:
left = 0, top = 0, right = 150, bottom = **13**

[image]

My question is what's wrong in my code? How to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: You requested `SW_SMOOTHSCROLL`.  I bet this completes asynchronously: `ScrollWindowEx` call returns after scrolling by one pixel, and sets up the timer to scroll 12 times more. `updateRect` reflects the initial one-pixel scroll.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Documentation fail, then, most likely

Comment: OP, if you post a [mre] I'll see if I can find a way to get this to work.  I'm not going to piece together a jigsaw of code.